# Зачем указателю нужно знать, какой тип хранится по адресу?

Tags: c++, указатели

Собственно, зачем мы пишем тип данных перед объявлением переменной-указателя? Если указатели хранят адрес ячейки, то какое им дело, что лежит по этому адресу?

Comment: Для навигации. `i++` для разных типов указателей сместит указатель на разное количество байт.

Comment: И при разыменовании для разных типов указателей будет осуществлён доступ к разному количеству байт.

Comment: Если нет дела до того что храниться по указателю, то используй `void*`

Comment: Не нужно писать конкретный тип, используйте `auto` там где возможно.

Comment: @älёxölüt, не нужно писать `auto`, используйте конкретный тип там где возможно. А то потом такой код без IDE читать невозможно

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb спасибо, обойдусь :) Писать явно тип там, где он не нужен - моветон. Особенно странно это выглядит при дублировании типа: `SomeType t = static_cast<SomeType>(expression);`.

Comment: @älёxölüt, Ну для примитивных случаев кто ж спорит. Как на счет такого `auto alice = get(); //Who the Fuck is Alice?`? Плюс надо держать в голове что `auto` "высыхает" `auto ref = some_map["key"]; ref = 42; //Wrong`. И это я не говорю о том, что `auto&&` это вовсе не rvalue ссылка...

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb тут претензия больше к `get` чем к типу. Надо имена нормальные давать. На заре c++11 лично мне приходилось отказываться от `auto` лишь по той причине, что IDE не могла нормально дальше распарсить. Сейчас такой проблемы в большинстве случаев нет.

Comment: @älёxölüt, уж не хотите ли вы сказать, что в имени `get` должно быть имя возвращаемого типа? Этак мы с вами сейчас венгерскую нотацию придумаем :) Я могу согласиться что `auto` приемлем в не которых случаях, и сказать "используйте конкретный тип там где возможно" было преувеличением, но и вы согласитесь что "используйте `auto` там где возможно" это тоже нездоровая крайность

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb просто по "там где возможно" это не значит "везде, где позволяет компилятор". Контекст тоже важен. Например, какой-нибудь `bool c = f() > g()` лучше, чем `auto`, имхо.

Comment: @älёxölüt `auto` ухудшает понимание программ (особенно чужих) и тем самым провоцирует ошибки

Comment: @avp вы же на с++ не программируете насколько я знаю.

Comment: @älёxölüt, я его не люблю, но часто вынужден иметь дело с чужим кодом на нем

Comment: Не помню как в си, но в дельфи есть типизированные указатели и не типизированные... что нужно, то и используешь, меньше путанки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Собственно зачем мы пишем тип данных перед объявлении
>   переменной-указателя?

Собственно за тем же, зачем мы указываем тип переменной. Когда приходит время работать с разъименованным указателем (то есть с переменной), то транслятору нужно знать какой это тип, чтобы правильно применять операции к этому типу.

> Если указатели хранят адрес ячейки то какое им дело что лежит по этому
>   адресу?

Пока указатели просто хранят адрес им (то есть транслятору) все равно. Но когда начинается использование данных по этому адресу, то транслятору нужно знать тип этих данных.

UPD1:

Нужно понимать, что (к примеру) когда суммируются два целых (int) числа, то транслятор вызывает одну функцию. А когда суммируются два float числа, то транслятор вызывает совсем другую функцию. Поэтому в программировании важна не только информация об операциях над переменными, но и также не менее важна информация об типах этих переменных.

Comment: Добавлю, что для программиста читающего текст программы, этот тип еще более важен, чем для компилятора.

Comment: @Chorkov иногда да, но чаще всего нет. `auto` решает.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее, чтобы компилятор знал с какими данными он работает,и как с ними можно манипулировать. Чтоб при разыменовывании указателя знать на какую память он ссылается - размер типа(байты). 
Всё таки C++ - статически типизированный язык программирования.

Answer (score 0):

Считается, что указателями сложно управлять. Довольна часто неверная инициализация указателей приводит к ошибкам, которые трудно обнаружить. Если компилятор будет знать, какой тип данных будет хранится по указателю, то некоторые ошибки можно будет избежать.

Также при инкрементировании указателя, программа должна знать размер типа данных на который указывает указатель.

Если не хотите объявлять тип указателя, то всегда можно использовать пустой тип void.

Answer (score -1):

Если представить, что тип переменной - это улица, а значение переменной - это собственно номер квартиры, тогда можно понять, зачем нужет тип. Компилятор не в состоянии найти квартиру без адреса, + ко всему типы данных очень сильно влияет на функционал переменной. Поэтому и нужно использовть тип данных при инициализации переменной-указателя.